# How to insert nvarchar value in a query string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query string which is

```
   var projectid = sqlConn.Query<int>("insert into project (name,customer_id, service_id,user_id) values (@name,@customerid,@serviceid,@userid);SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(); ", new { name = Name, customerid = Customer, serviceid = Service, userid = userId }).Single();
```

where name is a nvarchar field. Now I know I need to use 'N' character and I have tried the followings

```
'N@name'
N'@name'
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: As Andy indicates, the N specifier is only used with string literals. If your code isn't working as you require, I suspect it's somewhere in how your anonymous class gets mapped into parameters by your ORM - if that's the case, you ought to add information about what's happening that makes you suspect it's not working and add a tag for your ORM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `N` prefix with variables.

It is needed only with explicitly typed strings (string constants) like `insert into ... values(N'some text', ...)`

If your `name` variable contains unicode string - then no special actions are required.